# Resampling dataframe is producing unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Long question short, what is an appropriate resampling freq/rule?  Sometimes I get a dataframe mostly filled with NaNs, sometimes it works great.  I thought I had a handle on it.

Below is an example,

I am processing a lot of data and was changing my [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) frequency and notice that for reason certain resample rules produce only 1 element in each row to have a value, the rest of elements to have NaN's.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date']=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='5/08/2018')
```

Creating some example data,

```
df['data1']=np.random.randint(1, 10, df.shape[0])
df['data2']=np.random.randint(1, 10, df.shape[0])
df['data3'] = np.arange(len(df))
```

The data looks like,

```
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)

            data1  data2  data3
date                           
2018-01-01      7      7      0
2018-01-02      8      8      1
2018-01-03      2      7      2
2018-01-04      2      2      3
2018-01-05      2      5      4
(128, 3)
```

When I resample the data using [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) I get an unexpected results.

Below I resample the data every 3 minutes.

```
resampled=df.resample('3T').mean()

print(resampled.head())
print(resampled.shape)

                     data1  data2  data3
date                                    
2018-01-01 00:00:00    4.0    5.0    0.0
2018-01-01 00:03:00    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:06:00    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:09:00    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-01 00:12:00    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Most of the rows are filled with NaN besides the first.  I believe this due to that there is no index for my resampling rule.  Is this correct? '24H' is the smallest interval for this data, but anything less leaves NaN in a row.

Can a dataframe be resampled for increments less than the datetime resolution?

I have had trouble in the past trying to resample a large dataset that spanned over a year with the datetime index [formatted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) as %Y:%j:%H:%M:%S (year:day #: hour: minute:second, note: close enough without being verbose).  Attempting to resample every 15 or 30 days also produced very similar results with NaNs. I thought it was due to having an odd date format with no month, but df.head() showed the index with correct dates.

Comment: All your dates have midnight time period: `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resample **lowering** the frequency (downsample), then
one of possible options to compute the result is just *mean()*.
It actuaaly means:

- The source DataFrame contains **too detailed** data.
- You want to change the sampling frequency to some **lower** one and
  compute e.g. a mean of each column from some number
  of source rows for the current sampling period.

But when you **increase** the sampling frequency (upsample), then:

- Your source data are **too general**.
- You want to change the frequency to a **higher** one.
- One of possible options to compute the result is e.g. to
  **interpolate** between known source values.

Note that when you **upsample** daily data to 3-minute frequency then:

- The first row will contain data between *2018-01-01 00:00:00* and
  *2018-01-01 00:03:00*.
- The next row will contain data between *2018-01-01 00:03:00* and
  *2018-01-01 00:06:00*.
- And so on.

So, based on your source data:

- The first row contains data from *2018-01-01* (sharp on midnight).
- Since no source data is available for the time range between
  *00:03:00* and *00:06:00* (on *2018-01-01*), the second row contains
  just *NaN* values.
- The same pertains to further rows, up to *2018-01-01 23:57:00*
  (no source data for these time slices).
- The next row, for *2018-01-02 00:00:00* can be filled with source data.
- And so on.

There is nothing strange in this behaviour. *Resample* works just this way.
As you actually upsample the source data, maybe you should **interpolate**
the missing values?

Comment: Yes, I should interpolate my data.  I'll need to do some reading on this for Pandas.  Unless you have a nifty spiel about it?